# Inverse of a function exists if these conditions are met?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, inverse-function

Suppose a function's domain and range are restricted to the nonnegative reals. Are there any functions in this set which don't have inverses?

**Constraints**

1. The only parabolic form the function can take is of the form $x^{2n}$ i.e if $P(x) = x^{2n} +Q(x)$ then $Q(x)$ is a zero polynomial.
2. The function is not of the form $\frac{k}{x^{2n}} + c$
3. The function is neither trigonometric, nor exponential, nor logarithmic.

Comment: What about, say, $x^4 - 2 x^2 + 2$?

Comment: @grixor That's why I gave the constraint number 1. I'll elaborate it to make it clearer.

Comment: I'm not understanding your constraint... What do you mean by "only parabolic form"? What about other functions, like sin?

Comment: @grixor I'll add more constraints

Comment: You understand that we can always define function without actually writing down a formula for it, right? I think you can't add enough formula constraints to prevent non-injective function. But here's another: $f(x) = 0$ if $x$: irrational; 1 if $x$: rational.

Comment: @grixor I know that you can define piece-wise functions. Please do not try to be difficult. I'm sure you know what I mean in my question. The function in question should have a single definition, not piecewise.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46082/discussion-between-grixor-and-airdish).